# How to Add Custom Data as a New Column in the WooCommerce My Orders list in My Account page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am trying to add 1 column to WooCommerce > My Account > Order Page.

With Jet-Engine I added a field called **"url-from-download"** inside the Customer Order in WooCommerce.

There inside the customer order I select the PDF.

The code below adds the **Invoice column**, and a Text called **"Downloads"**, but it cannot extract the File as a url for me to download.

Where I'm I getting it wrong??

```
/**
 * Adds a new column to the "My Orders" table in the account.
 *
 * @param string[] $columns the columns in the orders table
 * @return string[] updated columns
 */
function th_wc_add_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {

    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {

        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

        // add ship-to after order status column
        if ( 'order-total' === $key ) {
            $new_columns['url-from-download'] = __( 'Invoice', 'textdomain' );
        }
    }

    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'th_wc_add_my_account_orders_column' );

/**
 * Adds data to the custom "url-from-download" column in "My Account > Orders".
 *
 * @param \WC_Order $order the order object for the row
 */
function th_wc_my_orders_url_from_download_column( $order ) {

    $url_from_download = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'url_from_download', true ); // Get custom order meta
    echo ! empty( $url_from_download ) ? $url_from_download : 'Download';
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_url-from-download', 'th_wc_my_orders_url_from_download_column' );
```

Answer (score 0):

> I added a field called "url-from-download"

you have stated in question that your field is called `url-from-download` but in your code, you're using `url_from_download`

There is a difference in dash (-) & underscore (_) so make sure you're using the correct meta key in `get_post_meta`

**UPDATE**

as per the discussion, I am assuming you're getting the url but you need it as button style that you can click.

To do that you need to add `<a>` tag in your code, the code will be like this.

Replace `echo ! empty( $url_from_download ) ? $url_from_download : 'Download';` line with below code

```
echo ! empty( $url_from_download ) ? '<a class="button" href=" ' . esc_url($url_from_download) . ' ">Download</a>' : '';
```

Comment: I already did it and it does not work. The Download text is still a plain text does not become a download button, to download the file that is loaded inside the Slug or ID "url-from-download".

```$url_from_download = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'url-from-download', true ); // Get custom order meta
    echo ! empty( $url-from-download ) ? $url-from-download : 'Download';```

Comment: If you're getting the url and your problem is you're not getting a link then you have not added any `<a></a>` tag to make a link, link text doesn't convert to an anchor link, you'll have to create it. I am updating the answer and adding what you have to write to make a link.

Comment: Like this?

```$url_from_download = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'url-from-download', true ); // Get custom order meta
    echo ! empty( $url_from_download ) ? $url_from_download : 'Download';```

Comment: I am not sure about the meta key, You know what key you have used to store the information. I have updated my answer and added the code to make a clickable link button from the URL.

Comment: Your code does not work, the text download disappears...

You know why, because I am using Jet-Engine, and I added a field called Media, when a customer buys, the field appears and you go and click on it and select from your media library the file or the pdf...

I think your code is more to put a url, right?
It is better to upload everything to Drive and put a url https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=

Comment: This way we avoid overloading the web site... and use drive as a base to upload the files.

I changed the field from Media Type to Text Type. I pasted a url from drive but your code doesn't work either.

Comment: Since I don't know what meta field Jet Engine uses to store metadata and if you're getting values from `get_post_meta` so I can't give 100% working code as I cannot test the things. you can debug what you're getting in `$url_from_download` and if your meta key is wrong then you can fix your meta key and validate if you're getting url from it then you can create an anchor tag and make a link from url.

Comment: The system adds directly to the "shop_order"

This says Jet-Engine

Name/ID
Name of the meta field/key/ID. Under this name the field will be stored in the database. It must contain only Latin letters, numbers, `-` or `_` characters.
<br>
select >url-from-download
<br>

Object type.
Object type of the current meta box: field or design element. To close the action of the previously selected Tab or Accordion group, use the `Endpoint` option.
<br>
select > field
<br>
Field type
Meta field type. Defines how the field will be displayed on the edit page of the entry.

select > text

Comment: I already solved it... it was to change

$url_from_download = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'url_from_download', true ); // Get custom order meta

To this

$download_url = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'url-from-download', true ); // Get custom order meta

A button like the View button already appears.